# Compare the token from an email to a user's token for account activation

Tags: email, token, cakephp-3.0, activation

I need to send a user an email with a link that they can click on to activate their account. Here is my code:

```
//ADD METHOD FROM USERS CONTROLLER, THIS SENDS THE EMAIL WHEN A NEW USER IS ADDED

 public function add()
    {
    $user = $this->Users->newEntity();
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        $user = $this->Users->patchEntity($user, $this->request->data);


        $newAuthToken = bin2hex(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(16));

        $user['authtoken'] = $newAuthToken;
        $user['activated'] = null;

        if ($this->Users->save($user)) {
            $this->Flash->success(__('The user has been saved.'));

            $ms='Click on the link below to complete registration ';
            $ms.='urlhere.com/users/activate/t:'.$newAuthToken.'';
            $ms=wordwrap($ms,70);


            $email = new Email('default');
            $email->viewVars();
            $email->template('default')->viewVars(array('user' => $user))
            ->emailFormat('html')
            ->to($user['email'])
            ->from('admin@example.com')
            ->subject('Hello ' . $user['email'])
            ->send($ms);


            return $this->redirect(['action' => 'index']);
        } else {
            $this->Flash->error(__('The user could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
        }
    }

    $groups = $this->Users->Groups->find('list', ['limit' => 200]);
    $answers = $this->Users->Answers->find('list', ['limit' => 200]);
    $courses = $this->Users->Courses->find('list', ['limit' => 200]);
    $this->set(compact('user', 'groups', 'answers', 'courses'));
    $this->set('_serialize', ['user']);
}
```

Here is the function that should compare the email token(from the link) with the tokens in the Users table and set the timestamp to Activated if they match:

```
//ACTIVATE FUNCTION FROM USERS CONTROLLER, SHOULD SET TIMESTAMP FOR ACTIVATED
public function activate($id = null)
{
if (!empty($this->passedArgs['t'])){
    $tokenhash = $this->passedArgs['t'];
    $results = $this->User->find('first', array('conditions' => array('authtoken' => $tokenhash)));


        if($results['authtoken']==$tokenhash) {
        $this->User->id = $results['id'];
        $this->User->saveField('activated', current_datetime());
        $this->Flash->success(__('The user has been saved.'));
        return $this->redirect(['action' => 'index']);
        exit;
    } else {
        $this->Flash->error('Tokens do not match');
        return $this->redirect(['action' => 'index']);

    }
}
}
```

Any ideas as to why this isn't working?

Comment: You get an error? Blue screen of death? Nothing at all? Does it act like all is well, but no email is sent? The email is sent, but to the wrong address? The email arrives, but it doesn't contain the link? It does contain the link, but the user can't click on it? Or something else?

Comment: It redirects me to the login screen, no flash message and the activated field is not updated.

Comment: That's stuff that should be in your question! Please edit it, and also add your auth component (which you are probably using) configuration/calls.

Comment: You're using `->id` and `->saveField` in the `activate` function. Those are Cake 2 concepts. Why aren't you saving it like you do in the `add` function?